# Retry with compensation activity in camunda

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, camunda

I have 3 microservices and am trying to implement compensation activity for each service. Now let say after an error compensation event triggered and now this compensation activity itself throwing error.
If compensation activity fails, i want to retry it for 5 times. Here is the sample code i have implemented but its not working. Any suggestions on this.

```
public static BpmnModelInstance createSaga() {
    // define saga as BPMN process
    ProcessBuilder flow = Bpmn.createExecutableProcess("poc");

    // - flow of activities and compensating actions
    flow.startEvent()
            .serviceTask("Project2").name("Save Project2").camundaClass(SaveProject2.class)
            .boundaryEvent().compensateEventDefinition().compensateEventDefinitionDone()
            .compensationStart().serviceTask("RollbackProject2").camundaClass(RollbackProject2.class).camundaFailedJobRetryTimeCycle("R5/PT5S").compensationDone()
            .serviceTask("Project3").name("Save Project3").camundaClass(SaveProject3.class)
            .boundaryEvent().compensateEventDefinition().compensateEventDefinitionDone()
            .compensationStart().serviceTask("RollbackProject3").camundaFailedJobRetryTimeCycle("R5/PT1M").camundaClass(RollbackProject3.class).compensationDone()
            .serviceTask("Project4").name("Save Project4").camundaClass(SaveProject4.class)
            .boundaryEvent().compensateEventDefinition().compensateEventDefinitionDone()
            .compensationStart().serviceTask("RollbackProject4").camundaClass(RollbackProject4.class).compensationDone()
            .endEvent();

    // - trigger compensation in case of any exception (other triggers are possible)
    flow.eventSubProcess()
        .startEvent().error("java.lang.Throwable")
        .intermediateThrowEvent().compensateEventDefinition()
        .compensateEventDefinitionDone()
        .endEvent();
// ready
BpmnModelInstance saga = flow.done();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can activate Asynchronous Continuation on the Service Task handling the Compensation which allows you to configure retry-options on the compensation.

Comment: Still not working-     flow.startEvent()
            .serviceTask("Project2").name("Save Project2").camundaClass(SaveProject2.class)
            .boundaryEvent().camundaAsyncBefore(true).compensateEventDefinition().compensateEventDefinitionDone().compensationStart().serviceTask("RollbackProject2").camundaClass(RollbackProject2.class).camundaFailedJobRetryTimeCycle("R5/PT5S").compensationDone()
            .serviceTask("Project3").name("Save Project3").camundaClass(SaveProject3.class)
.boundaryEvent().camundaAsyncBefore(true).compensateEventDefinition().compensateEventDefinitionDone()

Comment: I did not express it clearly enough: asynchronous continuation needs to be added to the service task handling the compensation, not the compensation boundary event. I edited my response.

Comment: Sorry for responding late, actually got stuck with other tasks...

Comment: Still not working-
flow.startEvent().serviceTask("Project2").name("Save Project2").camundaClass(SaveProject2.class).boundaryEvent().compensateEventDefinition().compensateEventDefinitionDone().compensationStart().serviceTask("RollbackProject2").camundaClass(RollbackProject2.class).camundaAsyncBefore(true).camundaFailedJobRetryTimeCycle("R5/PT5S").compensationDone().serviceTask("Project3").name("Save Project3").camundaClass(SaveProject3.class).boundaryEvent().compensateEventDefinition().compensateEventDefinitionDone().compensationStart().serviceTask("RollbackProject3").camundaAsyncBefore(true)